# Piecewise function turns into colored table

Tags: tables, color, cases

For a document that has both a bi-colored table as well as a separate piecewise function, the piecewise function instead gets recognized and turned into a table.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{white}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 
        \rowcolor{gray!50}
        \hline
        \textbf{One} & \textbf{Two}\\
        \hline
        Text & More Text\\
        Even More & Text\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \[
    \begin{cases}
        0 & t<0\\
        1 & t>0
    \end{cases}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have `\rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}` on the wrong place. it should not to be in document preamble but till before table, where you like to use:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
{
\rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c| }
        \hline
        \textbf{One} & \textbf{Two}\\
        \hline
        Text & More Text\\
        Even More & Text\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
    \[
    \begin{cases}
        0 & t<0\\
        1 & t>0
    \end{cases}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]